# What is the greatest number of baskets that Mikayla can make if she wants to put the same amount in each?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, word-problem

She had 60 apples and 72 pears and we want to split them equally into baskets.
I'm kinda confused because I'm in third grade and I'm learning this.

Comment: The [education] tag is only meant to be used for questions about the pedagogy of education, such as "How frequently should tests occur to make sure that students are following along?"  or  "Should I make references to the fact that once students reach higher levels and more abstract settings some of the rules I'm teaching them will no longer be true?"  The tag is *not* meant to be used just because the question came up during the course of *your* education.

Comment: If the unknown is "number of baskets", this number must exactly divide both 60 and 72 so that she can "split them equally" into that many baskets.  The problem is to find the *greatest common divisor* of 60 and 72.

Answer (score 4):

Because the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of 60 and 72 is 12, Mikayla can make 12 baskets of apples and oranges, with each basket having 5 apples and 6 oranges.